# ASP.NET API user linked to Token never changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

The api runs on localhost, the request come from a Angular2 based application and the api is secured using OWIN and OAuth 2.0. I don't know what part of the code I should paste here because I don't know where the problem could be.

Scenario:
User 1 logs in on client application (requests a Token from the API)
User 1 gets Token : XXXX...
User 1 looks for his data and gets his data back from the server
User 1 logs out of the client application and the Bearer token is removed from localStorage

User 2 logs in (same application session, same server session) and gets a Takon from the API
User 2 gets Token : YYYY...
**User 2 looks for his data but gets the data from User 1**

The server gets a different Token for User 2 but when looking at

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

The server still thinks it is User 1.

When logging out I also call the api/Account/Logout but this does not change anything

```
public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        return Ok();
    }
```

When I restart the localhost server and log in with the User 2 than I get the correct data but then the scenario is just switched (User 1 gets data from User 2).
If you need more code (however I did not change anything related the the AccountController) just tell me and I will look it up.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: APIs don't usually have a sign out feature. A token server will validate and identify the client by the token which typically expires after a certain amount of time. I suppose redesigning the authentication is not an option?

Comment: @Crowcoder If the correct user is found using the Token, and I get two different Token for the 2 users, why is the server telling that it is both the same user? That's what I don't understand. I know that a logout is not really needed, a different Token should be enough to see it as a different user

Comment: It is impossible to tell without the code. I would think you could debug through it and figure it out. You are not going to get any  (quality) answers because it is unanswerable.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know, but I was hoping that this was a common problem or a obvious one because when I debugged, all the correct information is used when logging in, it's just the way from the Token to the User.Identity where something funky happens.

Answer (score 0):

Pass from client some parameter to check if still the same user or has changed. If so, logout and Connect again.

Comment: What do you mean with the "logout and Connect" again?

Comment: var AutheticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

Answer (score 0):

imho, you still using bearer user1 token, thats why server still think who access is user1 .

to check that true or not, you can use [Authorize(Users = "user1")] // or you can change to user2 to check if user 1 or 2 have permission or not .